# Error while processing route, Expected an object as `data` but was undefined while using custom Serilalizers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using a customer serializers, and only overriding the extract method to deserialize the data coming from the server.

It's simple, and as follows

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extract: function(store, primaryType, payload, id, requestType) {
    var i, record, payloadWithRoot;
    // if the payload has a length property, then we know it's an array
    if (payload.length) {
      for (i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
        record = payload[i];
        this.mapRecord(record);
      }
    } else {
      // payload is a single object instead of an array
      this.mapRecord(payload);
    }
    payloadWithRoot = {};
    payloadWithRoot[primaryType.typeKey] = payload;
    this._super(store, primaryType, payloadWithRoot, 1, requestType);
  },
```

But while running the code, I get an error thrown from `at Ember.Object.extend.push (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:74329:15)` where the data is undefined. I'm calling `this._super()` from the extract method as suggested, and have confirmed that the modified data I'm sending up is not undefined when calling this._super()

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with calling `this._super`. Despite the documentation, this actually requires a `return` in front of it since that's the function which is returning the actual deserialized value so this fixed the issue:

```
return  this._super(store, primaryType, payloadWithRoot, 1, requestType);
```